# Waiting for a script to load in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So it seems Vue is not waiting for Stripe to load, natural behavior most probably. I tried coding a watcher to wait for it but it didn't block render until loaded, am I missing something?

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="px-8 pt-6 pb-12">
      testing
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        head: {
            script: [
                { src: 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/' },
            ],
        },
        data() {
            return {
                stripeReady: false,
                stripeInterval: null,
                elements: null,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            stripeReady: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    clearInterval(this.stripeInterval)
                    this.render()
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            let localThis = this
            this.stripeInterval = setInterval(function() {
                try {
                    Stripe('pk_test_');
                    localThis.stripeReady = true;
                }
                catch {}
            }, 500)
        },
        mounted() {
            let stripe = Stripe('pk_test_');
            this.elements = stripe.elements();
        }
    }
</script>
```